# RegEx - Select characters only if is single?

Tags: regex, replace

I need replace any `&(0-9a-z)` to `#$1` but only if `&` is single so not `&&.`

I try something like: `([^&]|)(&(0-9a-z))` but that just selecting all, or `[^&](&([0-9a-z]))` but then work only if `&` isn't first char ;/

EG:
"&5My text &&6it's awesome&a!!! &!!" = "#5My text &&6it's awesome#a!!! &!!"

So how to select this only if there is one `&` char even if it's first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both negative lookbehind and positive looahead for this regex:

```
(?<!&)&(?=[0-9a-z])
```

And replace with only `#` without using any group capture.

Comment: Works great! I will use it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can so this using negative look-behind assertion to make sure matching `&` is not preceded by another `&`.

```
(?<!\&)\&[0-9a-z]
```

Comment: o! That great! so `(?<!a)b` looking for `b` that isn't preceded by `a` ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. Also `(?<!\&)` is not part of the match.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you may be able to use `/[&]{1}/g` if my memory serves correctly (although this may be too aggressive), the {1} indicates 1 occurrences and the g indicates the match may occur more than once.
This will most likely need alot of tweaking to make it perform correctly, i have always used http://www.visibone.com/regular-expressions/ it is an absolute godsend.

Comment: Hyyym, that don't work for me, match `&5` in `&&5` but should skip it.

Comment: sorry, i thought it might do that. i hope my link can help you :)